# Define customized error pages with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

Using Spring with java configuration only, is possible define something similar to

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/notfound</location>
</error-page>
```

fragment of `web.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define an error page at servlet container level, which forwards to your custom controller.

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

  @Override
  public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/error"));
  }
```

}

Comment: I want to capture the Tomcat exceptions, for example if I put an incorrect Url I want to catch that and return my personalized page. With that examples I only can capture the exceptions inside the @Controller

Comment: I'm not using Spring Boot, just Spring with java configuration

Comment: I think it's not possible to configure it through java configuration. https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-50  or http://explodingjava.blogspot.in/2010/05/servlet-30-annotations.html however you can create a filter